# Which software/website is used to make diagrams like these? These look really good and this seems to be the most popular style I see in publications

Tags: graphics, software, ieee, website, electrical-engineering

[image: EE circuit diagram]

I see this style of diagrams in most good IEEE conference papers/journals and wish to know which software is used for these? They seem to be able to lighten parts of diagram, use multiple colours etc.

Comment: Suitable to stackOverflow or Tex forums. Not here...

Comment: Don't know, but may be look here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_4)%E2%80%94Circuit_Diagrams_Using_Circuitikz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software to draw illustrative figures in papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/software-to-draw-illustrative-figures-in-papers)