# Free and easy-to-use tools/softwares to draw scientific diagrams for physics

Tags: graphics, software, lecture-notes

I am typing some physics lecture notes for which I am using TeX. What good options are available to draw freehand diagrams easily and also convert them easily to pdf, png, jpg, etc that I can attach to my TeX document. I do not need very sophisticated software like those that would be needed, for example, for writing a textbook. I need to draw schematic, understandable diagrams, for example, the kind of diagrams that one draws on the blackboard of a physics classroom. Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Comment: Why do you want it to be online?  Inkscape is the obvious option.

Comment: draw.io could be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Software to draw illustrative figures in papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/software-to-draw-illustrative-figures-in-papers)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making neat pen and ink diagrams, then scanning them to pdf, or taking good pictures with your phone.

It's good for students to see that you don't need fancy software to create informative diagrams. Then you can ask for diagrams in exercises.

I would even recommend this for a textbook. There's nothing unprofessional about careful handwork.